# Posting Comments to WordPress with WPAPI

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api, netlify, wp-api

I'm using [Netlify event-triggered webhooks](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/#event-triggered-functions) to call a script that's designed to post a new comment to the WordPress API. I'm trying to implement [wpapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi) to make the POST request but not sure if I'm hooked up properly.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    let body = JSON.parse(event.body).payload

    if (body.form_name == 'comment-form') {
        // I assume I have to authenticate here
        var wp = new WPAPI({
           endpoint: 'https://example.com/wp-json',
           username: 'username',
           password: '123456'
        });

    ...
```

I then form the data to pass in... From what I can tell from the [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#create-a-comment), I can pass in a name, comment, and a post id. I'm not sure if I'm missing a parameter as I can't find any documentation about required params.

```
// url encode - not sure if this is required
let comment = {
    author_name: encodeURI(author_name),
    author_comment: encodeURI(author_name),
    post: body.data.postId
}
```

I then try calling `wp.comments().create()` passing in the object and setting up a callback:

```
wp.comments().create(comment, function(args) {
     console.log(args) }
  ).then(function( response ) {
     console.log( response );
  }).catch(function (err) {
     console.log(err);
  });
```

I am using this function in a [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) project and am utitlizing [gatsby-source-wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#create-a-comment) to pull data from a WordPress site, if that makes any difference.

When I run this function in Netlify, in the function log, there is no response or error message.

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed, Basic Auth plugin in your WordPress webiste?

Comment: I have installed [Basic Auth API](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) on my WordPress site but it has now seemed to have broken the pulling of data from [gatsby-source-wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#create-a-comment). I'll revisit this once I figure out what's going on.